# Stage all files in tig

Tags: tig

In `tig` command line tool for git, you go to the status view and you press `u` to stage a file. What I am curious about is how to perform that actions multiple time without repeating the word `u`. Is this possible to stage multiple files or all files with just one key combo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is not possible out of the box, you can configure it via your [tigrc](https://jonas.github.io/tig/doc/tigrc.5.html) file. As an example, assuming that while you are in the stage view, you want to map the `A` key to the `git add -A` bash command. Here is what you will need to add to your `tigrc` file:

```
bind status A @git add -A
```

The syntax is pretty straightforward, the `@` flag just means that the command output will not be shown.

Comment: This works beautifully, thank you so much @scebotari66

Comment: What if I want to add just the file I'm looking at in the "status" view? How do I represent "current highlighted file" in `.tigrc`?

Comment: @Corel, There is a standard `u` keybinding for that. In https://jonas.github.io/tig/doc/manual.html, check the "View Specific Actions" section.